# Maven assembly of assemblies

Tags: maven-2, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a multi-module maven 2 project which uses assemblies (via maven-assembly-plugin at the package phase) to package each module in a certain way.  I am then trying to use another module to combine these assemblies into a distributable "installer" package.   For the installer module I can see the default jar from my other projects but nothing I do seems to give me access to the extra assemblies.  It seems from the documentation that this should be possible so I assume I'm either doing something wrong or it's a bug in Maven?  I've been stuck with this for several days now so any help would be appreciated!

Following on from a comment I have created a test project on github to demonstrate the this, the proj1 module creates 2 jar files.  I would expect the assembly generated in the "package" module to include them both but it doesn't it just includes the main project jar.

https://github.com/unluckypixie/maven-packaging-test

Please note: I know the content of the jars for proj1 one are the same in this example - but they are not in my real life situation, I don't think what is in the proj1 files is relevant to the problem.

if you run:

```
mvn clean package
```

And do `ls proj1/target/*.jar` you should see:

```
proj1/target/proj1-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
proj1/target/proj1-1.0-SNAPSHOT-proj1-assembly.jar
```

If you look in the package jar :

```
jar -tvf package/target/package-1.0-SNAPSHOT-package-assembly.jar
```

You will see something like:

```
     0 Mon Jul 30 16:27:00 BST 2012 META-INF/
   106 Mon Jul 30 16:26:58 BST 2012 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
     0 Mon Jul 30 16:21:46 BST 2012 package/
  2358 Mon Jul 30 16:21:44 BST 2012 package/proj1-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
  2363 Mon Jul 30 16:21:46 BST 2012 package/package-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

I want to know how why the `proj1/target/proj1-1.0-SNAPSHOT-proj1-assembly.jar` is not in there too.

The packaging assembly looks like this:

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.0.xsd">

    <id>package-assembly</id>

    <formats>
        <format>jar</format>
    </formats>

    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>

    <moduleSets>
        <moduleSet>
            <useAllReactorProjects>true</useAllReactorProjects>

            <includes>
                <include>org.test.parent:*</include>
            </includes>

            <binaries>
                <outputDirectory>/package/</outputDirectory>
                <unpack>false</unpack>
            </binaries>
        </moduleSet>
    </moduleSets>
</assembly>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to get this working by using the attachmentClassifier in my assembly file, e.g:

```
    <moduleSet>
        <useAllReactorProjects>true</useAllReactorProjects>

        <includes>
            <include>org.me:*</include>
        </includes>

        <binaries>
            <outputDirectory>/output/dir</outputDirectory>
            <unpack>false</unpack>
            <includeDependencies>false</includeDependencies>
            <attachmentClassifier>my-assembly</attachmentClassifier>
        </binaries>
    </moduleSet>
```

Thanks to khmarbaise for your help, I might not have used your solution but it helped me get there!

Answer (score 0):

I have created a [example project based](https://github.com/khmarbaise/assembly-of-assemblies) on your posting (made some fixes to it) and if i do a

```
mvn clean package
```

i found under package/target/package-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-package-assembly.zip which contains

```
package/
package/proje1-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
package/package-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

which looks ok to me. The question is what did you expect?

Comment: If you look in your proj1 target folder there should be two output jars, the one you have got and another one with the assembly name as a suffix, e.g. "proje1-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-proj1-assembly.jar" that one is the one i'm after.  So I to summarise there should be 3 jars in the output file as it stands, two called proj1* and one called package*.

Comment: Following your example I have created a test project on git hub ... I've not posted on stackoverflow before so I didn't think of that.

Comment: Added pull request to fix your problem.

Comment: There should be two pull requests otherwise you can take a look into the forked project.